# Can the dates be changed on a Schengen visa that has already been issued?

Tags: schengen-visas

Is it possible to change the dates on the visa when it has already been issued and stamped into the passport?

My girlfriend just applied and got her visa to visit me. Unfortunately, it turns out I will have to go on a long business trip during those dates. Is there anything we can do to change them? Is asking the consulate to cancel this one and reissue a new one an option?

For clarification: it’s a 90 day visitors visa.

I’d greatly appreciate your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  There's no reason why you can't apply for a new visa to cover your new plans.  You can also ask the consulate to cancel the existing visa.  You can include evidence of your trip to add credibility to your change in plans.